# Explanation of Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula, which I can't understand how it works:

```
=DOLLAR(("4/"&C1)/7+MOD(19*MOD(C1,19)-7,30)*14%,)*7-6+1
```

When the value in C1 is 2020, it returns a 43934, and 43577, when the value is 2019.

Could somebody explain how the formulae works?

Edit: Realise that it finds Easter Monday. What I need to be able to amend the logic to find the Greek Orthodox Easter Monday. However, I don't quite understand the logic it uses to find the Western Easter Monday in the first place.

Comment: Have you tried evaluating the formula (`Formulas -> Formula Auditing -> Evaluate Formula`)? Is there a function used in the above formula that you don't understand?

Comment: It finds Easter Monday.

Comment: Do you want to modify it someway?

Comment: To find the Greek Orthodox Easter Monday will require a new formula as it determined differently. Unless it is always a fixed difference from Easter Monday.

Comment: Even though the Julian and the Gregorian calendars are just shifts of each other, the Orthodox Easter is not just a shift of the Western Easter (for one thing, they sometimes coincide). It might be easier to find a formula which already works for Orthodox Easter than to try to modify this one.

Comment: [HERE](https://peltiertech.com/calculating-easter/) there is a UDF that will calculate it.

Comment: @ScottCraner Nice link. A surprisingly involved topic. Lunar calendars don't interact with nonlunar calendars in any straightforward way, and the topic becomes even more tricky when two different non-lunar calendars are involved.